# Loading assembly in a new app domain fails with FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, mono

Loading an assembly works fine in the default app domain, (using `Assembly.LoadFrom(dllFile)`) but when I do it in a new application domain it throws a `FileNotFoundException`:

```
AppDomain ModDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("TestTest");
Assembly assembly = ModDomain.Load(dllFile);
```

I've tried setting the ApplicationBase when configuring the new domain but it's having no effect.

```
new AppDomainSetup {
    ApplicationBase = "/path/to/dll/folder"
}
```

I'm trying both absolute and relative paths, and I've toyed with the `PrivateBinPath` and `PrivateBinPathProbe` properties, with no luck.

What might I be missing?

**Edit**

When I use the `ApplicationBase` mentioned and the assembly name, the error includes a lot more assembly info it's somehow getting:

> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'TestMod, Version=1.0.6468.36459, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Yet when I use any other file path variation or `AppDomainSetup` variation it just says:

> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'TestMod' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

So, one version seems to know more about my assembly than the others.

Problem is, I'm on Mono 2.0, so I'm having trouble finding example of setting permissions properly... if that's the cause.

Comment: I'm not sure what default permissions a new domain is created with but can you try enumerating files in the folder of the dll (using absolute path), if that fails too your domain probably lacks the necessary rights

Comment: Is it possible to run a local class inside a new domain? Since I can't load a dll there I'm not sure how to load my directory scan code into that domain.

Comment: Though reading some of the docs, it does seem like `FileIOPermission` is required and it's a good bet it's not set. I can't seem find up to date docs on how to set app domain permissions though... google points to outdated/obsolete docs

Comment: I don't know haven't needed to use appdomains manually in a while but the createdomain should have an overload that takes permissions